# QR Scan "Unrecognized format" mycelium "Mastering Bitcoin'

Tags: qrcode, mastering-bitcoin

Noobie here.
In Ch. 2 of Antonopoulos' "Mastering Bitcoin", I try to scan figure 2-2 (per his instruction) using a recently installed Mycelium on my Android.

Why do I keep getting "Unrecognized format"? How do I properly scan this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mh i'm try with [Bitcoin android wallet](https://bitcoin.org/en/wallets/mobile/android/bitcoinwallet/) and work, this is the result

[image]

Can be your wallet have a bug?